# Directory API - How to use pageToken in Users List

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

Using Google App Script with GSuite's Directory API. I want to list all users from the root OU. This code pulls all users from the directory and filters out those who are members of sub-OU.

The code.

```
/**
* LIST USERS FROM ROOT OU
*/
function listUsers() {
var optionalArgs = {
domain: 'mydomain.com',
maxResults: 500,
orderBy: 'givenName'
};
var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
var users = response.users;
var counter = 0;
if (users && users.length > 0) {
Logger.log('Liste des utilisateurs...\n');
for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var user = users[i];
  /* FILTER OUT SUB-OU, PRINT ONLY MEMBERS IN ROOT OU */
  if (user.orgUnitPath == '/') {
    counter++;
    Logger.log('Result #%s', counter.toString());
    Logger.log('\nName : %s\nEmail : %s\nOU : %s\n', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail, user.orgUnitPath);
    }
}
} else {
Logger.log('Nothing found...');
}
}
```

Now the function listUsers has a cap of 500 results but my organisation has way more users accounts.

I know my problem will be solved by the use of the pageToken parameter and this has been asked time and again. I have been reading through many posts on the subject, and yet, I am not finding any clear explanation and a way to adapt this to App Script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
function listUsers(){
  var values = [],
  users = [],
  userListQuery = {},
  nextPageToken = '',
  listObject = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    query: "isSuspended=false",
    maxResults: 500
  },
  i = 0,
  j = 0;

do {

if (nextPageToken && nextPageToken !== '') {
  listObject.pageToken = nextPageToken;
}  

var userListQuery = AdminDirectory.Users.list(listObject);

// Si plus de maxResults retourner à nextPageToken
nextPageToken = userListQuery.nextPageToken;

// Ajout de résultats à la liste
users = users.concat(userListQuery.users);

} while (nextPageToken);

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
// Filtrer les résultats
if (users[i].orgUnitPath == '/') {
  j++;
  Logger.log('Résultat #%s', j.toString());
  Logger.log('\nNom : %s\nCourriel : %s\nOU : %s\nDépartement : %s\n', users[i].name.fullName, users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].orgUnitPath, users[i].orgDepartment);
  }
 }
}
```